# Can I use a PHP API with my react-redux-node website

Tags: php, node.js, reactjs

I am in the planification process of a big web app project and I haven't officially choose the stack of languages/framework I will use. I have a PHP MVC background but just learned React-Redux with a Node.js server. I like it and want my project to be modern and efficient so I'd like to use that.

Problem is: one big feature of my app consist in dynamically generating docx and pdf document with great flexibility. The documents are saved and downloaded by users. I am planning on using Docxpresso API for that (http://www.docxpresso.com), but it is a **PHP** API...

I'm not an expert with servers/stack/api... would it be possible to do that? All my website and main server with react-redux-node and still use docxpresso to generate my docx and pdf?

Comment: You can use React with any backend you want. Now, if you want to do all the fancy universal rendering and what not, that's a different story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In regards to:**

> All my website and main server with react-redux-node and still use docxpresso to generate my docx and pdf?

You can do whatever you want. You can have 2 "backend" servers, with one taking care of serving the main application (NodeJS & React/Redux) and another taking care of generating and retrieving the pdf and docx from docxpresso (PHP). Now, is this ideal? It depends... If you are starting from scratch, I would advice against doing so. If you have something already, there might be ways around it.

Another point to consider is: Are you willing to maintain both codebases? Do you have time for it? If you responded "YES" to both of those questions, then the scenario I described above might suit your needs. Fortunately, there are other alternatives as well. Stacks like [MEAN](http://meanjs.org/) or [MERN](http://mern.io/) are famous because they use JavaScript for both front-end and back-end alike, eliminating the use of different programming languages for different parts of your application.

**Conclusion**:

After analyzing your situation, and having used both PHP and NodeJS, I can give you the following advice:

- If you want to stick to PHP because you are experienced with it, go for it and just stick to PHP. Use a framework like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) or something lighter like [Lumen](https://lumen.laravel.com/) to make your life easier and avoid using NodeJS. Drop in docxpresso and code your front-end in React/Redux.
- If you want to try NodeJS, there are equivalents of docxpresso for JS, one of them being [Reporting Cloud](http://www.reporting.cloud/) that support JS clients. Adopt MEAN or MERN, or create your own home-brewed framework. NOTE: If you do decide to go the JS route, the learning curve might be a little steep, since you have to learn both a front-end and back-end framework.
- If you want to do a mixture of both PHP and JS (as mentioned in your question), consider doing most of your work in NodeJS and React/Redux, and you could maybe use an [AWS Lambda](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-introduction-function.html) to execute your PHP code in the cloud and retrieve its results from your NodeJS environment.

I hope this helps!